# Cron job daily not running

Tags: bash, scripts, cron

I'm having trouble with setting a cron job to run daily when I enter the script to `/etc/cron.daily` when I put it there it doesn't run at all like it should be doing.

I setup a script so that it can keep my repository up-to-date and then download any new packages it finds that needs upgraded. I didn't want to do `crontab -e` because it doesn't let me set its own individual file to run this script because it only seems to dump it into `/tmp` directory. Here's what my cron script looks like;

```
#!/bin/sh

30 22 * * 0 apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y
```

There doesn't appear to be any indication that this works, except for the fact I get errors relating to apt in `mailx` saying

```
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root
```

I would of thought this ran at root level inside of `/etc/cron.daily` since it's owned by root? The permissions read as `drwxr-xr-x   2 root     root       4096 Sep 28 06:02 cron.daily` I wasn't too sure if I should add `sudo` to the command because then it would just sit there waiting for a password to be entered.

also how would I be able to get it to log what packages updated so I can review them later? or does apt already log these to it's own log file somewhere? if so where is it? I would like it to just output the name and versions of the packages installed it upgraded from to display something like this into a log file, ie;

```
<package> @ <version> --> <new_package> @ <version>   <date> <time>
```

Answer (score 0):

A few things...

1. `30 22 * * 0` means every Sunday at 10:22pm. Not daily. Use a * in the fifth time field if you want every day of the week.
2. Files in `/etc/cron.d/` take a slightly different format. The second argument (after the time string) sets the user it will run as. To do things this way your file should read:

   ```
   30 22 * * *  root  apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y
   ```
3. Files in `/etc/cron.daily/` are acually supposed to be standalone scripts, *not cron-formatted strings*. To do things this way, your file should read:

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   set -e
   apt-get update
   apt-get upgrade -y
   ```
4. **And perhaps most importantly...** if you want to automate updates, I'd suggest something like `apticron`. It gives you much better control over *what's* installed automatically and what isn't. It also sends out emails with changelogs, etc... I think it's what you want.

Comment: So what you're saying is I'd have put the cron job into `/etc/cron.d` pointing it to the script inside of `/etc/cron.daily` where the script resides for it to run daily. is that right?

Comment: No they're different approaches and currently you're somewhere in the middle. Pick one, or better yet, pick `apticron`.